# How do I prove that for almost every $x\in X$ the sequence $f_n(x)$ is convergent?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathbb{A},\mu)$ be a measure space. Suppose that $f_n$ is a sequence of integrable function from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}||f_n-f_{n+1}||_1\lt \infty$$

How do I prove that for almost every $x\in X$ the sequence $f_n(x)$ is convergent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n=f$ is a.e. $\mathbb{R}$-valued. We have that, by monotone convergence,
$$\int\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|f_n-f_{n+1}|d\mu=\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\int|f_n-f_{n+1}|d\mu<\infty$$
So $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|f_n-f_{n+1}| \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$ but then since
$$\bigg|\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(f_{n+1}-f_{n})\bigg|\leq\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|f_n-f_{n+1}|$$
then also $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(f_{n+1}-f_{n})\in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$ which implies
$$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}(f_{n+1}-f_{n})=\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(f_{k+1}-f_k)=\lim_{n \to \infty}(f_2-f_1+f_3-f_2+...+f_n-f_{n-1})=$$
$$=\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n -f_1 \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$$
We already know that $f_1 \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$ so define $f= \lim f_n$:
$$(f-f_1)+f_1 \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu) \implies f \in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$$
This means that $f$ is a.e. $\mathbb{R}$-valued.